# Nil value in virtual attribute not caught by Rails validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rspec

I have this Rails model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :number_format, :inclusion => { :in => ["1,000.00", "1.000,00"] }

  def number_format=(format)
    self.currency_delimiter = format[1]
    self.currency_separator = format[5]
  end

  def number_format
    "1#{currency_delimiter}000#{currency_separator}00"
  end

end
```

---

The problem is that when I test it with RSpec...

```
it "is invalid without a number_format" do
  expect(FactoryGirl.build(:profile, :number_format => nil).errors_on(:number_format).size).to eq(1)
end
```

...I get this error:

> 1) Profile number_format is invalid without a number_format
>        Failure/Error: expect(FactoryGirl.build(:profile, :number_format => nil).errors_on(:number_format).size).to eq(1)
>
> ```
>    expected: 1
>         got: 0
> ```

How is this possible?

I thought `nil` won't get validated due to the validation method I put in place.

Comment: Does your model actually have a attribute `number_format`? I only see a setter method with a similar name. Is there a database column named `number_format` or a method with that name?

Comment: Yes, there is also a getter method. I just added it above. There is no database column with that name, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FactoryGirl.build` just initializes a record, it doesn't try to save the record to the database and therefore doesn't call `valid?` on the record. Without calling `valid?` the instances errors will always be empty.

Try this instead:

```
it "is invalid without a number_format" do
  profile = FactoryGirl.build(:profile, :number_format => nil)

  expect(profile).to_not be_valid # `be_valid` actually calls `valid?`
  expect(profile.errors_on(:number_format).size).to eq(1)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Really appreciated. In the meantime I managed to figure out that the error I posted above was caused by my `factories.rb` file where I had not defined the `number_format` virtual attribute. I am not 100% sure but I think that's what caused it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using virtual attributes, I think the errors are saved to `:base`. You should check `expect(FactoryGirl.build(:profile, :number_format => nil).errors.size).to eq(1)`.

Comment: Nice try but it gives me the exact same error, unfortunately.